# Connecting MySQL Workbench to a AWS RDS Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I will start this by saying I have read all of the posts I have found on here regarding this issue and have troubleshot all of the solutions suggested, and none have worked. I have also tried all of the suggestions from the AWS and MySQL websites themselves to no avail. I believe the issue is a Security issue, but I'm not sure where the issue is. All of these were set to Public. So far I have done the following:
MySQL side:
-Installed Visual Studio 2019 toggled so that it can use the MySQL for Visual Studio in case I need it (Currently, my plan is to use Eclipse as my IDE, but this is my first time interfacing with MySQL in Java and I'm not sure if I will be able to use the Connector directly with Eclipse or if I will need this)
-I installed 8.0.31, but rolled it back believing it may have been an issue with 8.0.31 being newer than 8.0.30 and seeing there is no documentation saying this version is compatible with RDS in Amazon's documentation
-Installed 8.0.30 as both Developer and Custom (installed MySQL Server, MySQL Workbench, MySQL for Visual Studio, MySQL Shell, Connector/J)

From RDS I have done the following:
-Created 3 different Databases, 2 using the "Standard" mode, 1 using the "Easy" mode. The 2 using the "Standard" mode were toggled with one using an EC2 and one not using an EC2.
-For all 3 Databases, I went in and Edited the Inbound Rules to add a rule of "All traffic" and "Anywhere-IPv4". I'm aware this is actually a security risk, but this is for a school project and I'm literally trying to connect to the Database. Currently, I'm the only person who needs to connect to the Database and when I can actually do it, I will limit it to my IP Address.

I have tried connecting from the Workbench itself and also from the Command Prompt, but I cannot find any more suggestions for what can be the issue. I have also changed the name of the Masteruser (to "root" and "root user") and simplified the Masterpassword. This is for a school project so no confidential information is in it. I have literally spent an entire day trying to solve this issue and have no idea what else it could be unless it is the admin as I am not the Admin. I have seen a suggestion to make sure the Subnet for the Internet Gateway is active, but I haven't seen information on how to actually verify this, so if this is likely the issue, information on how to check this would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Start from scratch, it's a 60 second job to create and a nightmare to debug off you've got something wrong.

1. Create MySQL RDS
2. Make sure you set it to public in the above step
3. Ensure the security group you use or created allows access from your IP address
4. The default admin username on AWS RDS is 'admin' not 'root' like what the default admin username is for MySQL
5. Put the connection details into MySQL Workbench

That's it

Comment: I've done this several times and I've toggled several different settings, but this hasn't worked. There's a different issue. I was saying I have even changed it from admin to root and root user in RDS, not in MySQL, I see where I didn't make that clear. I have matched up all of the information from RDS to MySQL and followed several tutorials, but there is another issue. I'm guessing it is a security issue. For what it is worth, I am not the owner/admin of the AWS the RDS is on, so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you create the RDS instance, or was that created by someone else? Are your security group settings allowing inbound 3306 connections from your IP address?

Comment: I figured it out. I created the RDS, however, I was not the owner of the primary AWS account the RDS was made on, I am just an IAM user. The primary account holder had set up the VPC settings in such a way that it defaulted all VPCs to automatically set all inbound traffic exclusively to his IP address and he didn’t know he did it or know how to fix it. I worked with him and resolved it by creating a new RDS with a new VPC and changing the new VPC’s inbound rules.

Comment: Excellent, well done. This is the v0.1 of security group rules. Remember this. This is often one of the most common issues that come up, that traffic can/can't route through the different layers in the technology stack. Please feel free to accept the above answer as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it to connect. A little background incase anyone ever has this issue again. I followed all of the instructions from AWS, MySQL, stackoverflow, and several YouTube and other tutorials. The issue stemmed from the fact that I was not the owner/admin of the primary AWS the RDS was on. When I set everything up, it defaulted to a VPC that had already been created for Elastic Beanstalk where I did not have permission from the Security Group to connect to the VPC. I figured that out early, but then when I went to create new VPCs, it was incorrectly recognizing the primary AWS admin's IP as the default for the connection whenever I tried to create the RDS VPCs, so I had to toggle in the VPC security inbound section to add myself as a recognized IP address, even though I was already added (I actually had added all inbound traffic after getting frustrated) to the primary inbound rule for the RDS database itself.